# Как загружать изображение в приложение?

Tags: c#, uwp

Подскажите как сделать, чтобы по нажатию кнопки открывался файлообменник и предлагал выбрать файл, а после он отображалось в неком ListView.

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под `файлообменник`?

Comment: Проводник, проще говоря. Но я уже научился открывать его и даже выводить путь к изображению, с помощью FileOpenPicker. Но никак не могу сделать, чтобы это изображение выводилось в ленту...

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите. Какой файловый обменник (локальный, сетевой, облачный), что именно вы хотите отобразить имя файла, картинку, путь.

Comment: Локальный, отобразить картинку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открытие диалога с помощью `FileOpenPicker`. 
Ссылка на описание: [FileOpenPicker Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207847)

---

Отображения изображения с помощью `BitmapImage`
Ссылка на описание: [BitmapImage class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx). Полезная ссылка: [Image.Source Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source.aspx)

---

В ссылках имеется подробное описание и примеры.

Создайте объект Image в XAML, без источника и каких-либо других значений свойств. А код C# примерно будет выглядеть так:

```
FileOpenPicker open = new FileOpenPicker(); 
StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync(); 
if (file != null) 
{ 
    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read)) 
    { 
         BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(); 
         bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 600;
         await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream); 
         Scenario2Image.Source = bitmapImage; 
    } 
}
```

> Используйте метод SetSourceAsync, если используются источники
>   изображений, которые доступны для задания объектов Image только во
>   время выполнения, например файлы изображений, которые пользователь
>   может выбирать, открыв FileOpenPicker в пользовательском интерфейсе.

Comment: А можно мне, как начинающему, добавить немного комментариев после условия?)

Comment: @Denisok, откройте вот эту статью [Image.Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source.aspx) - тут достаточно подробно описано, думаю разберетесь.

Comment: А можно еще вопросик, как сохранять загруженные изображения, как какой-то объект, или прост путь? (например если картинки из интернета я каждую ссылку сохраняю в Iist и по нему строю GridView)